# Where does 'color_puts' come from?

Tags: ruby

I can't find where the color_puts would come from in the mod_passenger installer... any ideas?

Comment: Please be clearer. I shouldn't have to do my own research to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked up myself just what you meant, since it's more fun than working.

Check the `require` statements at the top of the file - you'll see that there are only 3 possible sources, given that `color_puts` is not a Ruby standard.

Turns out, it's in [abstract_installer.rb](http://github.com/lennart/passenger/blob/master/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_installer.rb).

```
def color_print(text)
    STDOUT.write(ConsoleTextTemplate.new(:text => text).result)
    STDOUT.flush
end

def color_puts(text)
    color_print("#{text}\n")
end
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks.
Looks like http://github.com/lennart/passenger/blob/master/lib/phusion_passenger/console_text_template.rb has a bit to say as well, (kinda figured from the lack of escapes haha) but have a good one